# Установка параметров для Graphics в OnPaint

Tags: c#, winforms, графика, usercontrol

Экземпляру класса Graphics можно установить такие параметры как SmoothingMode и т.д. Проблема в чем: мне кажется, что установка этого параметра при каждой перерисовке выглядит избыточно.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

   // Вызовы методов рисования
}
```

Есть ли возможность установить параметры один раз, как например, можно в конструкторе контрола установить такие флаги:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

Comment: Это пееропределенный метод чего-то, а чего именно вы не сказали. `можно в конструкторе контрола установить такие флаги` - почему вы решили, что в конструкторе то, о чем вы говорите, нельзя так сделать?

Comment: У контролов есть метод OnPaint, который вызывается при перерисовке, и там в аргументе есть e.Graphics - текущий экземпляр графики, в котором все рисование осуществляется. Мой вопрос в том. могу ли я этот экземпляр получить до момента перерисовки или как-то выполнить все настройки единожды, чтобы не выполнять их при каждой (это важно) перерисовке.

Comment: `SmoothingMode` нужно задавать каждый раз при вызове `OnPaint`, это нормально и by design. Еще `e.Graphics` - это каждый раз новый экземпляр класса для каждого вызова, задать однократно не получится.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать!